# Can we run job through SSIS packages in server1 which scheduled in server2?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-job

Can we run job through SSIS packages in Server1  which scheduled in server2(that job is currently disabled in server 2)

Kindly give me suggestions.

Comment: I'm selecting SSIS because,i need to run disabled job in Server2  along with other SSIS tasks in a same SSIS package in Server1

Answer (score 0):

You could execute sp_start_job in Server2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

or you could try with:

[image]

in Package - Reference Type select External reference (VS 2010)